# NextJS Property 'set' does not exist on type 'ReadonlyRequestCookies'

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

I'm trying to set cookies inside the server actions function in Next.js 13.4.1.
[Example code](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options)

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
 
async function create(data) {
  'use server';
  cookies().set('name', 'lee');
  // or
  cookies().set('name', 'lee', { secure: true });
  // or
  cookies().set({
    name: 'name',
    value: 'lee',
    httpOnly: true,
    path: '/',
  });
}
```

But i got error with message:
`Property 'set' does not exist on type 'ReadonlyRequestCookies'`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you aware this is an alpha feature?

Comment: If you are using typescript 5 try to downgrade typescript 4. ts v5 gives too many issues with different npm packages

Answer (score 1):

That's strange, because it should normally work.

maybe you using it in a "use client" component? you can"t use it there. Use "cookies-next" instead.

in my project server side components i use`const nextjsCookies = cookies();`
to initialise the cookies
and set the cookie with `nextjsCookies.set("test", "test");`